# I install react-tooltip to spfx and although the install sucsses if I try use <tooltip> the project faild

Tags: reactjs, typescript, spfx

I install react-tooltip on spfx,
and although the installation goes well,
I use  and it doesn't work

Create a tooltip when hovering over a text with the mouse it displays it
As long as the REACT-TOOLTIP library is installed, I get an error when running, only when I download the installation does the project run

this is error:@microsoft/sp-build-web/node_modules/webpack/lib/dependencies/HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.js:88:6)
at HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.getErrors

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.